# On the Proof that Hausdorff spaces are Hausdorff in the box and product topology

Tags: general-topology

Theorem 19.4. from Munkres' topology states if each space $X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff then $\Pi_\alpha X_\alpha$ is a Hausdorff space in both the box and product topologies.

The proofs I can find of this proceed as follows: let $x$ and $y$ be distinct points of $\Pi_\alpha$, so there is some index $\beta$ such that $x_\beta \neq y_\beta$. Let $U$ and $V$ be disjoint neighborhoods of $x_\beta$ and $y_\beta$ respectively in $X_\beta$. Then the open sets $W = \Pi_\alpha U_\alpha$ where $U_\beta = U$ and $U_\alpha=X_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \neq \beta$ and $Z = \Pi_\alpha V_\alpha$ where $V_\beta = V$ and $V_\alpha=X_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \neq \beta$ are disjoint neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$ in $\Pi_\alpha X_\alpha$.

I am confused about this because if both $W$ and $Z$ are equal to $X_\alpha$ for $\alpha \neq \beta$ wouldn't that make them non-disjoint? I only see how they would be disjoint for the $X_\beta$. Clearly I'm missing something here.

Comment: The title of your question does not make any sense. What you mean becomes clear in the body of the question, so I suggest that you edit the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though $[0,1]=[0,1]$, it is still true that $[0,1]\times[0,1/2)$ is disjoint from $[0,1]\times(1/2,1]$. We have taken a square and excised the dotted halfway line; the two comonents are disjoint *even though all the "$x$" coordinates are shared*.

For $(x,y)$ to live in the intersection of these sets, we require $x$ to be in both $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]$ (ok, no problem...) *but also* we require $y$ to be in both $[0,1/2)$ and $(1/2,1]$ - this *is* a problem! That's why the intersection is empty; you have to look at all the factors of the product, and if there is a disjointness even in one of the coordinates then that is enough.

I've used a $2D$ example for visual clarity. Generalise this.

Answer (score 0):

$W \cap Z = (\Pi_{\alpha}U_{\alpha})\cap(\Pi_{\alpha}V_{\alpha}) = \Pi_{\alpha}(U_{\alpha}\cap V_{\alpha}) = \emptyset$, because $U_{\beta} \cap V_{\beta} = \emptyset$.